# If I format my SD card or replace with a new SD card, what will I lose?

Tags: external-sd, data-recovery

If I format my SD card or replace with a new SD card, what will I lose?

1. What Personal data
2. What Application data
3. What downloads

In short I want to find what, where and how data is stored on SD.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Settings -> Applications -> Manage Applications -> SD Card to see what apps are on the SD card.  Other things that might be on it include pictures and videos.  There aren't a lot of things that default to the SD card, but it depends on your device and software.  The easiest way to find out what's there is just to look!

Answer (score 1):

To see what's on your SD card, you can use an app like [ASTRO](http://www.appbrain.com/app/astro-file-manager/com.metago.astro).

Or, you can hook your device to your USB port and enable mounting and look at with your computer's file explorer. Or pop the card into a card reader.